# format string in python 2.5 unpacking a list

Tags: python, tuples, string-formatting, iterable-unpacking

Is there a way to do something like this in Python 2.5:

```
b = ('{!s}'*3)
b.format(*[i for i in xrange (3)])
```

because this is not working:

```
b = ('%s'*3)
b % (*[i for i in xrange (3)])
```

Comment: `[i for i in xrange(...)] == range(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = '%s' * 3
b % tuple(range(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = '%s'*3
b % tuple(i for i in xrange (3))
```